# Sort columns while keeping rows intact

Tags: tablesorter

Let say I have three columns, each column has over 1,000 entries

A  B  C

1  2  6

5  3  7

7  4  8

Now I reorder the elements in column A as

5

1

7
...

How can I sort columns B and C so that I have

5  3  7

1  2  6

7  4  8
...

Excel has the "custom list" sort feature that can do exactly what I want. All I need to do is enter column 1 as "5, 1, 7, ..." into the "custom list". However, it doesn't work if my column 1 has 1,000+ entries (I cannot paste the list there). I am looking for a solution with awk or grep.

Comment: How exactly is the "custom list" determined? Are you arbitrarily choosing "5, 1, 7" as the order? Or is there some logic to it?

Comment: Hi, there is no "simple" logic on how that column is ordered. The order of entries in that column is determined by a separated algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to a Perl solution:

```
($in, $list) = @ARGV;
open IN, "< $in" or die;
while ($line = <IN>) {
    @F = split /\s+/, $line;
    if (defined $h{$F[0]}) {
        die "ERROR:  multiple input lines have first column $F[0]\n";
    }
    $h{$F[0]} = $line;
}
open LIST, "< $list" or die;
while ($line = <LIST>) {
    @F = split /\s+/, $line;
    if (defined $h{$F[0]}) {
        print $h{$F[0]};
    } else {
        die "ERROR:  no match found for $F[0]\n";
    }
}
```

Save this file as "script"
Save your input data as "input"
Save your custom list as "list"
Run: `perl script input list`

**How it works:**
Iterate through the input file which contains columns of data, separated by whitespace.  If your input file is comma-separated, change `/\s+/` to `/,/`
Split line into fields array `@F`
Store line into hash `h`, keyed based on first field `$F[0]`

Iterate through the list file
Split line into fields (this handles trailing whitespace)
Print contents of hash for that key

Sanity checking is also done